# sql: how to unite fields into a vector in a select query?

Tags: sql

What I mean is:

```
...
select...
where (a=1 and b=1) or (a=1 and b=2) or (a=2 and b=3) or(a=3 and b =2)
```

can this be simplified to something like

```
...select...
where (a,b) in ((1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,2))
```

the idea is not to check the fields separately, but unite them into a vector and check the vector value.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't state your DBMS, but this:

```
where (a,b) in ((1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,2))
```

is valid (standard) SQL.

And it works (at least) in PostgreSQL, Oracle and MySQL:

SQLFiddle demo for PostgreSQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ffbcb/1
SQLFiddle demo for Oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a42cb/1
SQLFiddle demo for MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a42cb/1

As this is ANSI SQL other DBMS should support that too.

Answer (score 1):

For SQLServer2005+

Function CHECKSUM() calculates hash-value which is called as checksum. [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.your_table t
WHERE CHECKSUM(a,b) in (CHECKSUM(1,1),CHECKSUM(1,2),CHECKSUM(2,3),CHECKSUM(3,2))
```