# Double IN Statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Just curious about the IN statement in SQL.
I know I can search multiple columns with one value by doing

```
'val1' IN (col1,col2)
```

And can search a column for multiple values

```
col1 IN ('val1','val2')
```

But is there a way to do both of these simultaneously, without restorting to an repeating AND / OR in the SQl? I am looking to do this in the most scalable way, so independent of how many vals / cols i need to search in.
So essentially:

```
('val1','val2') IN (col1,col2)
```

but valid.

Comment: what rdbms are you using? MySQL, Oracle, sql server?

Comment: Your explanation text doesn't match the examples, might want to reverse that. :)

Comment: No, you have to use the quadratic expansion or use a cross join (which might not perform well depending on the exact query).

Comment: oops. :) right way round now. And is SQL Server 2008

Comment: To be clear: you want to confirm that {`'val1'`,`'val2'`} is a subset of {`col1`,`col2`}? That is, that `'val1' IN (col1,col2) AND 'val2' IN (col1,col2)`?

Comment: You could create a table of all your values you want to check against, then join on that table. Not sure how feasable it would be, depending on your use-case though.

Comment: If such a thing existed would at most save you the trouble of writing the `AND/OR` logic, there is no way to avoid comparing each value in the first set to each value in the second so performance wise it would be equivalent.

Comment: @Asad: such a thing **does** exist (it's standard SQL). But apparently SQL Server does not support it. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13178312/330315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this [(which I've also put on SQLFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5777):

```
-- Test data:
WITH t(col1, col2) AS (
    SELECT 'val1', 'valX' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'valY', 'valZ'
)
-- Solution:
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    -- Join all columns with all values to see if any column matches any value
    FROM (VALUES(t.col1),(t.col2)) t1(col)
    JOIN (VALUES('val1'),('val2')) t2(val)
    ON col = val
)
```

Of course, one could argue, which version is more concise.

Comment: this works, though as it is about as concise as iteration through one of the list and using an AND/OR, i guess I would side with ease of reading and using      'val1' IN (col1,col2) OR 'val2' IN (col1,col2)

Comment: `VALUES(..)` makes things a bit better. See the updated answer. But yes. If you only want to compare two columns with 2 values, use your regular `OR`-connected `IN` predicates :-)

Comment: It's really a shame that SQL Server does not support comparing of tuples like PostgreSQL, Oracle or DB2 (and as defined in the ANSI standard)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes it is. Also CUBRID, HSQLDB, and MySQL figure on the tuple-comparison-enabled databases. But then again, SQL Server's useful `VALUES(..)` table constructor isn't available in most DB's...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example you can do this in Oracle:

```
select x, y from (select 1 as x, 2 as y from dual)
where (x,y) in (select 1 as p, 2 as q from dual)
```